# Not able to scroll webpage on tap and scroll while on slider in mobile browser

Tags: jquery, css, responsive-design

I am having an issue. I have used a slier on a website and its working fine in web view. but while i am browsing it in mobile, i am not able to scroll the webpage when i tap and trying to scroll on the slider.

> BUT IF I TAP ON ANY OTHER SECTION EXCEPT THE SLIDER AND TRY TO SCROLL THE PAGE, THEN ITS WORKING FINE.

Having issue only on the slider.
[image]

In the above image if we tap on the slider section and drag it to up and down then nothing happens. And if i do the same on any other section then its scrolling the page properly.
I want that the slider also act as same as rest section. because its wearied that i am scrolling the page from top to bottom and when slider come in front and i want to scroll more it got freeze.

Please Help me to do that. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post the slider code? The slider is probably catching all touch events, and you'd need to override its touch handler.

Comment: please view the site in your mobile.
[http://projects.sudipta-dhara.com/forgood/](http://projects.sudipta-dhara.com/forgood/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the simplest solutions is to to use swipe slider. Here is the link https://github.com/thebird/Swipe